# Getting no values from context in Dialogflow

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

I have created a chatbot in Dialogflow in which when Welcome Intent is called, I receive the user's email id from an API and I stored it in context: *mail*.
I am accessing this email in another Intent to register the user but I get no value. Upon printing the context on the console, it showed the email id, then why not in the RegisterUser Intent?
I used the inline editor for fulfillment in Dialogflow.

Welcome Intent:

```
 function getmail(agent){  
  var myJSONOb = {
    "param1":param1
  };
    var options = {
      method: 'post',
      uri: 'my_API',
      body: myJSONOb,
      json: true
    };
    process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = false;
    return rp( options )
     .then( body => {
      let ctx = {'name': 'mail', 'lifespan': 15, 'parameters': {'email':body.mail}};
      agent.setContext(ctx);
     // this prints: { name: 'mail', lifespan: 15, parameters: { email: 'mymail@gmail.com' } }

     })
     .catch( err => {...
     });
  }
```

In register User:

```
  function registerUser(agent){
    let params = agent.getContext("mail").parameters;
    let email = params.email;
    agent.add("email "+email);
    //this just prints : 'email' and no value
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure which version you are? but you can do this like below also.
I think you are using NodeJS fulfillment webhook.

```
// Set the context
    agent.context.set({
            name: 'global_main_context',
            lifespan: 5,
            parameters: param
        });
// get the context
let globalContext = agent.context.get('global_main_context');
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: yes sorry for not making it clear. I am using the inline node.js fulfillment.

Comment: Still, you can try that method, I believe, It should work with inline editor as well.

Comment: I tried this but it gave this error: 
status": {
      "code": 10,
      "message": "Failed to parse Dialogflow response into AppResponse because of invalid platform response: Could not find a RichResponse or SystemIntent in the platform response for agentId: b655666c-93fe-4fad-939c-de5e70a2d48e and intentId: 06013eeb-8e66-47f1-85c6-8c35d6fdf7fb. WebhookStatus: code: 14\nmessage: \"Webhook call failed. Error: UNAVAILABLE.\"\n."
    }

Comment: which version you are using, I have used it with "dialogflow-fulfillment": "^0.6.1", on NodeJS client.

Comment: I am using 
    "dialogflow": "^0.6.0",
    "dialogflow-fulfillment": "^0.5.0"
Is this what might be causing the error?

Comment: I think, yes because those methods are available in the older version, if you check the docs, you can find new methods.